# How to get historical data from Yahoo's CSV API?

Tags: yahoo-finance

I'm rather new at this so I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong. So I was trying to get some historical data and online it said I should be able to import it from http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s= [insert ticker symbol] as show here: http://thesimplesynthesis.com/article/finance-apis#yahoo-csv-finance-api. However when I tried to click the link using any ticker symbol just to make sure it works, I keep getting this [image]